# Array of std::string in Ruby SWIG.

Tags: c++, ruby, swig

Currently in Ruby [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html) you can have an interface file of the form.

```
%include "std_string.i"
namespace std {
   %template(String_Vector) vector<string>;
}
```

And this way you can make a vector of string in Ruby. But I would like to create an array of std::string in ruby. This is for a gem that I am working on and this would really help speed things up.I have searched the documentation but could not find it properly. Any help is appreciated.